# remove a :before attribute on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a class on my images, and through `.images:before` an overlay is placed on it.
Now I would like to (with jquery for instance), remove that overlay on hover...

Here's what i though but doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.images').hover(function (){
           $(this).css('background','');
     });
});
```

Heres the css...

```
    .image {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.image:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('images/overlay.png');
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You could modify the stylesheet rules, but your best options is to avoid using that pseudo element. Pseudo elements have weird behavior when interacting with javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine pseudo selector with a pseudo element :

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.image:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('images/overlay.png');
}

.image:hover:before {
    display : none;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Re9bj/17/